# Why does hibernate/ehcache second level cache always miss within the same session?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I have a long-running EntityManager which I periodically clear().  I have a read-write cache configured on one of my entities.

I have done some investigation and I can see that the entity is present in the cache.  I can even see a cache hit from [net.sf.ehcache.Cache.searchInStoreWithStats()](http://ehcache.org/xref/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html#1868).  However, ehcache will not return the entity if its timestamp is later than the timestamp when the session was created: see [AbstractReadWriteEhcacheAccessStrategy.get(Object, long)](http://ehcache.org/xref/net/sf/ehcache/hibernate/strategy/AbstractReadWriteEhcacheAccessStrategy.html#67).

What is the reason for this behaviour?  Is there a way I can customise hibernate or ehcache to achieve cache hits within a single EntityManager?

Comment: sorry to point to the obvious, but have you overridden the equals and hashcode? If you've done that, are you sure they are correct?

Comment: On the entity?  Yes, I have.  I'm not sure that it should matter, though, because Hibernate doesn't store the entity itself in the second level cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a property of a read-write cache: you can't fetch an entity from the cache that was created in the same session.

A non-strict read-write cache doesn't compare timestamps, so this does achieve a cache hit after the first load().

Even better, a transactional cache populates the cache after persist(), so the very first load() will result in a cache hit.  Since my interaction with the databse is entirely within a single thread in a single JVM, I believe this is safe to use.

Comment: that kind of makes sense. If it's the same session, perhaps hibernate expects to find it in the 1st level cache, or perhaps it's waiting for a flush to see if the entity is even valid

Answer (score 2):

As the JavaDoc say: The timestamp says the Entity was created after the transaction started, so the transaction can't possibly see it (as per [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)).

So it seems that you have several transactions, say A and B. You start B, then A, then A creates instance X and then B tries to look up X -> cache miss since A isn't committed, yet (for example).

Comment: The entity was created after the _session_ was created, but it was created in a previous _transaction_.  And my application doesn't have any concurrent transactions.

Comment: EHCache thinks different, so chances are that you're wrong. I suggest to add logging the transaction creation/commit to make sure your expectations are met.

Comment: I have done logging and debugging.  I get cache hits when I create new sessions for each persist() and getReference() operation, but I get cache misses when I persist, commit, clear(), then getReference() all within a single session.